# How can i remove added inline css?

Tags: html, css

I'm a designer not developer "so mind the question if its too basic" and i was updating my word-press version.
www.majd-design.com

After updating my word-press version i got extra margin in my inline element{},

```
element {
    float: left;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
    height: 516px;
}
```

Can anyone advice how can i get rid of it, as this code isnt in CSS files or in the HTML index file.

Thanks

Comment: Really not sure what you mean. On the margin line, the values go round in a clockwise direction from top margin to left margin. If you delete the last 25px the left margin will take its value from the right margin i.e. 0px.

Comment: How do i set the 25px back to 0px, the attribute of margin-left: auto; so I'm not sure from where it gets the 25 value and how its calculated?

Comment: I don't think you can set it back to auto, but you can set it to something else with margin-left: [whatever]px !important;

Answer (score 3):

Adding `!important` to the end of a css attribute declaration will tell the browser to make sense of it and not to any other declaration of the same attribute, also when the other declaration has more priority than yours (and also inline css ;)).

You can use it like this:

`margin: 0px 0px 10px 25px !important;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Alter the CSS file.  If it's core to a theme or WP then you can also...
2. Create a child theme. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
3. Get a custom CSS plugin and override the CSS. https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

```css
element {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I installed the plugin and tried to added the code, with no result :(

Comment: Then it might depend on the logical order in which the styles are being applied.  Are the styles associated to WPCore, a plugin, or the theme?

Answer (score 0):

you might need to add more detail but i think its probably this section of the CSS

```
margin: 0px 0px 10px 25px
```

When its in shorthand like this it means:

```
top margin is 0px
right margin is 0px
bottom margin is 10px
left margin is 25px
```

Let me know if this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript , you can do

```
document.getElementById("myDivsId").style.margin = "0";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myDivsId").style.marginLeft = "50px";
```

(similarly for all 4 sides)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryt2q90s/)